# CSS animation not filling up vertical height correctly?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to create a searchlight/ spotlight effect that will highlight some text using CSS animations. [Heres a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RkDekkard/dow1ucge/14/).

However, my spotlight does not reach up to the top of the page and instead reveals the black background to different degrees throughout the animation.

What I'm trying to achieve looks something like this:

[image]

I was wondering if anybody had any ideas as to how to modify my spotlight to vertically fill the entire page?

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
  position: absolute;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.spotlight {
  position: relative;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 0vh;
  border-top: 100vh solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  border-left: 12vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 12vw solid transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100% 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-animation: move 7s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) scaleX(0.4);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) scaleX(0.4);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <h1>
    Some text
  </h1>

  <div class="spotlight spot1"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use display:absolute instead of relative and modify the code a bit ;)

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.spotlight {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  bottom: -20px;
  border-top: 140vh solid rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.493);
  border-left: 12vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 12vw solid transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform-origin: 50% 100% 0;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  will-change: auto;
  animation: move 7s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg) scaleX(0.4);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(30deg) scaleX(0.4);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    Some text
  </h1>
  <div class="spotlight spot1"></div>
</body>

</html>
```